# What is this dollar sign ($) icon in my Menu Bar?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, software

It just appeared this most recent time I opened my mac and I don't remember installing anything with this logo. It doesn't show any options for me to do anything when I click on it either. Have I been hacked?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try looking for the same logo/icon in Activity Monitor app. Energy tab will be shorter than others. Also, sort by name, most probably, it starts with S

Comment: Nothing, I've checked through all the tabs and can't find anything that has the same logo.

Comment: If you sort by CPU used, does any of the top processes look strange?

Comment: Not Particularly. The only thing that is slightly out of the ordinary is **iStat Menu Status**. Normally this wouldn't be strange but I deleted the app from my applications and I can't seem to kill this process.

Comment: You could force quit it, or `kill` using PID in terminal, if it doesn't break anything. Have you tried the trivial reboot?   (notify people using @ )

Comment: @ankiiiiiii kill what - the issue is the OP does not know what it is. ALso menu items usually take no CPU until they are clicked on. iStat Menus is an exception as it shows information

Comment: @Mark I meant killing the istat... process, just for the sake of removing the *out of ordinary* thing. And coincidentally it would have removed the menu bar icon too. I know that OP didnt identify the logo. Saw my comment above? Your second part addresses nohillside I guess. I suggested energy as all menu items(in my usage) show up there.

Comment: No tooltip? For shame!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is because you are using an expired trial version of iStat Menu Status. The app will display a dollar sign icon instead of the system stats icon.

Comment: AHHHHH this is it. This makes so much sense I can't believe I didn't think of it. opening up iStat prompted me to pay or uninstall, and after uninstalling the icon disappeared. Thank all of you guys for the help!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the icons appeared for no good reason.

[image: Multiple dollar icons in menubar on macOS]

To fix it, I had to Pause and restart iStat Menus:

[image: How to restart iStat Menus]